# How do I use loadlibrary to load this dll with all its headers?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, matlab, dll

I have a dll file, `irig106.dll`, that I produced from a compile in Visual Studio 2010. (The source code is [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/irig106/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/irig106/irig106lib/src/)). Notice the multitude of `.h` files in there; the main one is called `irig106ch10.h`, as far as I can tell.

I would like to import it into MATLAB via [`loadlibrary`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loadlibrary.html). I put all the `.h` files into their own folder, called "headers". Here's what I get:

```
loadlibrary('irig106.dll', 'headers\irig106ch10.h', 'addheader', 'config', 'addheader', 'stdint', 'includepath', '.\headers');

Warning: Warnings messages were produced while parsing.  Check the functions you intend to use for correctness.  Warning text can be viewed using:
 [notfound,warnings]=loadlibrary(...) 
Error using loadlibrary (line 418)
There was an error loading the library
"mydir\irig106.dll"
mydir\irig106.dll
is not a valid Win32 application.
```

So I'm not sure of a few things:

1. Why is `loadlibrary` claiming that the dll is not a valid Win32 application? It looks like based on my Visual Studio settings, I am compiling for Win32.
2. Per the `loadlibrary` documentation, I need to explicitly use `addheader` for each header file I want to include, and those headers need to be `#include`d in the base header file. In this case, I only include `config.h` and `stdint.h` in `irig106ch10.h` but I'd like to use all those other headers. Do I need to make a "header header" file where I include *everything*?

I guess I'm looking for a tutorial on how to use `loadlibrary` for complicated dlls with multiple headers like this, because there really isn't much in the way of examples on the internet. I'd love to see someone build the .dll (uncomment the `#define IRIG_NETWORKING` in `config.h`) and give a step-by-step.

Comment: Some common issues to check: 1) Is the DLL x64, or x86, does this match Matlab?  2) There are dependency issues with the DLL, ie. Matlab can't find a dll that irig106.dll needs

Comment: I'm using 64-bit MATLAB but it looks like the Visual Studio project is targeting Win32. Can I change this in VS?

Comment: In VS Express 2012 and 2013 (both free), yes.  In 2010, you need the professional version.  If so, where it say Win32, see if it says either x64 or Configuration Manager and setup a new x64 project by copying the 32 bit debug and release projects.